# Microsoft Access equivalent of OPENQUERY()

Tags: sql, ms-access, informix

We use multiple SQL databases of various types; one of them is an Informix database.

Some of our analysts are having issues pulling data from it, especially when using dates. Years ago I'm sure I saw someone using something similar to SQL Server's (T-SQL's) `OPENQUERY` in a more environmentally friendly manner. Is there still such a command in Access, or was I imagining things?

Comment: That depends what you're trying to do; `openquery` can do a few things.  If you're trying to execute a query on a remote server, I don't know of any built-in Access method to do that. I've used Access for "many versions" and I don't recall any such command.

Comment: ...but maybe you're thinking of the [**`DoCmd.OpenQuery` Method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openquery), which just... opens a query...?  Perhaps if you describe your actually problem, as opposed to your idea for a workaround, someone could suggest an *actual* solution. (See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).) ‎

Comment: @ashleedawg T-SQLs `OPENQUERY` is a way to open a connection to a linked server and passing an SQL query to that server, then retrieving the result. It doesn't open a query for viewing (similar to `OPENROWSET` but requires a linked server instead of specifying the connection string). `DoCmd.OpenQuery` is something entirely different.

Comment: @ashleedawg - Cheeky! No - I already knew the solution I needed, I used it once a long time ago, but could not for the life of me remember what it was.  I was already thinking of X when I chose X' as the answer. :o]϶

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access supports directly querying external data sources using Access's database engine and SQL dialect.

The syntax is the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM [ODBC;<ODBC DSN or connection string>].[External table name or view]
```

You can use this same syntax to update/insert tables.

Alternatively, if you need to use the SQL dialect of the external data source, use a passthrough query: Create -> Query Design -> Pass-through query. It auto-prompts for a DSN, but you can specify the DSN in the property pane.

Access does not support mixing it's SQL dialect with others (which you can do using OPENQUERY in SQL server), but you can query using Access's SQL off of pass-through queries which is essentially the same.

Comment: That's it, by Jove!  Pass-through queries.  I knew I had seen something along those lines.  Erik, you're a star.